# AutocompleteTextView is not updated dynamically

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am getting data (`List`) from an API and I am trying to update my `AutcompleteTextView` with this data.

This is how I currently do :
I have a `TextWatcher` which calls a the method to get the data in `afterTextChanged`, so every time the user stops typing the method is called, and the adapter is notified with ``notifyDataSetChanged :

```
//in onCreate
    addressAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,suggestions_address);
    at_address.setAdapter(addressAdapter);

...

@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            autoComplete(s);

            addressAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //suggestions_address is the updated list, and when I print it I can see the 
            //results so it is not empty
            Log.i("addresses",suggestions_address.toString());

        }

...

class SuggestionQueryListener implements ResultListener<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<String> data, ErrorCode error) {
        if (error != ErrorCode.NONE) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            suggestions_address.clear();
            for(int i = 0;i<data.size();i++){
                suggestions_address.add(data.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
public void autoComplete(CharSequence s) {
    try {

        String term = s.toString();
        TextSuggestionRequest request = null;
        request = new TextSuggestionRequest(term).setSearchCenter(new GeoCoordinate(48.844900, 2.395658));
        request.execute(new SuggestionQueryListener());
        if (request.execute(new SuggestionQueryListener()) != ErrorCode.NONE) {
            //Handle request error
            //...
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        //
    }
}
```

But it seems that the adapter is not really updated because it doesn't show the suggestions when I type something.
Also, before doing this with an `AutoCompleteTextView` I did it with a `listView`, with the same process, and everything worked well.

Any ideas or solutions would be really appreciated

**EDIT :** I noticed something really strange : the data is not binded to the adapter, because `adapter#getCount` always returns 0, even if the list is not empty. But when I remove `at_address.setAdapter(addressAdapter)`, the data adapter is updated and `adapter#getCount` returns the right number of elements.

I am really confused right now, please help !

Comment: What is inside autoComplete()?

Comment: It's the method I use to get the list, but it's working fine, I am sure the problem doesn't come from here. (If it was not working, `Log.i("addresses",suggestions_address.toString());` wouldn't print anything)

Comment: Please see my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808479/5128831

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<data.size();i++){
            suggestions_address.add(data.get(i));
        }
```

you can use just this:

```
suggestions_address.addAll(data);
```

you are calling notifyDataSetChanged after you start the request, you should call it after you get the result and update the suggestions_address, so call notifyDataSetChanged inside onCompleted